# Integration Services 2019 - Execute Process Task - WindowStyle ignored

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, bids, ssdt-2019

I recently migrated projects developed in Sql Server BIDS 2008 to Visual Studio Professional 2019 with SSIS extension.

After the upgrade all the packages are now up and running, but when I run them in debug mode, all Exectue Process tasks with WindowStyle property set to Hidden now display the console window. Other styles are ignored, too.

In BIDS 2008 debug could run in the background and I could do other stuff, but with some of these packages exeuting hundreds of tasks, it's very annoying and make other work impossible.

Comment: Is "StandardOutputVariable" property set or it is null?

Comment: @Hadi I already checked that, it's not set.